# Removing a portion of text

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to remove all the portion of text in square braces along with the braces, in TypeScript. How can I do this?

```
var text="All-Weather Floor Liner Package [installed_msrp]"
```

Comment: TypeScript has little to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, hope it helps

```
var text="All-Weather Floor Liner Package [installed_msrp]"

alert(text.replace(/\s*\[.*?\]\s*/g, ''));
```

This will also remove excess whitespace before and after the parentheses

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ayam9zcc/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript function string.replace

```
var text="All-Weather Floor Liner Package [installed_msrp]"
var myCleanedStr = text.replace(/(\[.*\])/g, "");
console.log(myCleanedStr); // Output is "All-Weather Floor Liner Package "
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a RegExp in conjucation with the replace function. Like this:

```
'All-Weather Floor Liner Package [installed_msrp]'.replace(/\[.*\]/g, '');
```